# Draw line connecting most data points in time series

Tags: python, line, connect

I would like to find out how to draw best fit line or line that connects the most points; one line for local minimas and the other line for local maximas.

Something like as with this picture:
[image]

Below are the codes for finding local minimas and maximas points

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
yf.pdr_override() 

startdate = dt.date(2016, 1, 1)
#enddate = dt.date(2018, 10, 22)
today = dt.date.today()
index_ticker = "^GSPC"
index_df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(index_ticker, start=startdate, end=today)

from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
n=50 # number of points to be checked before and after 

# Find local peaks/bottoms
index_df['min'] = index_df.iloc[argrelextrema(index_df['Adj Close'].values, np.less_equal, order=n)[0]]['Adj Close']
index_df['max'] = index_df.iloc[argrelextrema(index_df['Adj Close'].values, np.greater_equal, order=n)[0]]['Adj Close']

# Plot results
plt.scatter(index_df['Adj Close'].index, index_df['min'], c='r')
plt.scatter(index_df['Adj Close'].index, index_df['max'], c='g')
plt.plot(index_df['Adj Close'].index, index_df['Adj Close'])
plt.show()
```

I came across this tutorial, https://prappleizer.github.io/Tutorials/Plotting/Plotting.html which draw a best fit line with a shaded region of uncertainty.

[image]

It's what I'm looking for but I couldn't figure out how to apply onto time series to get the desired output as in the time series picture.

Appreciate if anyone can advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have your local minima and maxima, plot a linear regression on each of these sets of points. Use your favorite Python statistical package to do this.